# Can a stock split after its face value reaches ₹1?

Tags: stocks, india, stock-markets, stock-split, stock-dividend

Can a stock split after its face value reaches ₹1? Will the face value be less than 1?I am speaking in terms of the Indian stock market. Yes face value means par value.

Comment: I don't know about India, but in the US, many exchanges require their stocks to trade above $1, so when a stock value drops near $1, they are more likely to reverse-split (to increase the price per share and keep their listing) than to split. However it's entirely common for stocks to trade below $1 on the over the counter market. We even have the term *penny stocks* to describe those stocks.

Comment: You should also clarify, are you looking for an answer specific to the Indian market, or to other markets (and exchanges)?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "face value"? Do you mean the market price or the [par value](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/p/parvalue.asp)? Par value doesn't change, so the question might not make much sense.

Comment: What scenario are you imagining where the par value changes?

Comment: @ThePhoton  in case of a stock split

Comment: Stock split or merge cost money.  So it is up to the company to decide whether to split it to make it looks affordable. When the stock split, it will create more stock and dilute the earning per share.